VB.net Import .txt file to pre existing columns in Datagridview
first to me:
I'm fairly new in vb.net and still a beginner and reading many many guides/articles to improve myself but sadly I can't get over this problem.
I have a Form with data gridview and set the Columns in my Text:
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    table.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Sub

Now I want to import the text from a Text.File which I already created:
(it was created with the exact method like this one but not imported it was exported)
The text file looks like this:
1|a|a|a
2|b|b|b
3|c|c|c
To import the Textfile:
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim lines() As String
        Dim vals() As String

        lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\duidi\Desktop\Test\log3.txt")



        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step +1
            vals = lines(i).ToString().Split("|")
            Dim row(vals.Length - 1) As String
            For j As Integer = 0 To vals.Length - 1 Step +1
                row(j) = vals(j).Trim()

            Next j
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next i

    End Sub

To my Problems:
I want to change the width of the columns (maybe something else too like font, height)
but I have absolutely no clue how to edit the width of the columns while they are in a datatable.
I could add the columns via Form.Designer and change the width there but than I have no clue how to get the connections between datatable and columns.
What is the actual purpose of this program:
I want to export the data from a dataviewgrid (maybe encrypt it (later point))
than import the data in the exact same datagridview edit it and export again.
And so on.
I know there are many, many posts out there which describe the import/export to .txt file but I am still too new to adapt it on my own to my program, I need to see the solution on my own text. I could really need your help!
Sorry for my bad English I am not a native
Here is my full (functional) code
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim table As New DataTable("Table")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        table.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"))

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_export_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_export.Click
        Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\duidi\Desktop\Test\log.txt")

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Step +1

                If j = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    writer.Write(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString())

                Else
                    writer.Write(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() & "|")
                End If

            Next j

            writer.WriteLine("")

        Next i
        writer.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("export fertig")


    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_import_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_import.Click
        Dim lines() As String
        Dim vals() As String
        table.Clear()


        lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\duidi\Desktop\Test\log.txt")



        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step +1
            vals = lines(i).ToString().Split("|")
            Dim row(vals.Length - 1) As String
            For j As Integer = 0 To vals.Length - 1 Step +1
                row(j) = vals(j).Trim()

            Next j
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next i

    End Sub
End Class


lines(i) is already a string. Don't call ToString() if the object is already a string.

Access to columns and styles:
Dim columnIndex = 0
Dim column = DataGridView1.Columns(columnIndex)

column.Width = 100

column.HeaderCell.Style = New DataGridViewCellStyle With {
    .Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 20, FontStyle.Bold),
    .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
}

column.DefaultCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle With {
    .Font = New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic),
    .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
}

Here is the style documentation
What are your import problems? It is not clear from the question.
What is table object?

Hi, thanks for your Answer,
i dont have problems with import, i added my full code above(wich is stable and works), i just dont know how to add your code and where to add it. When i do it i get an Error.

@ChristianM. You use something like this right after you create the columns for the table.

We can simplify and improve performance for the import/export:
Private Sub btn_export_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_export.Click
    Using writer As New StreamWriter("C:\Users\duidi\Desktop\Test\log.txt")
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            Dim delimieter As String = ""
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1                                     
                writer.Write(delimiter & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString())
                delimiter = "|"
            Next j
            writer.WriteLine()
        Next i
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("export fertig")
End Sub

Private Sub btn_import_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_import.Click
    table.Clear()
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines("C:\Users\duidi\Desktop\Test\log.txt")
    For Each line As String() In lines.Select(Function(line) line.Split("|") )
        Dim row = table.NewRow()
        For i As Integer = 0 To line.Length - 1
            row.Item(i).Value = line(i)
        Next i
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next line
End Sub

Even better to get a real csv delimited field parser off of nuget (Split() has all kinds of edge cases).

I did it, thanks to "Konstantin Makarov"
was simple. had to define columns and datagridview....

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    table.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 200

End Sub


